# Publish MVC Project in Visual Studio 2012 Results in Empty Folder

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment

I am attempting to publish an MVC4 application from VS 2012 Pro running Windows 8 Pro. However, this is resulting in an empty directory at the publish root (as defined by the publish settings). I have the "All files in this project" selection for items to deploy and I am not attempting to publish any databases. Also, I'm only trying to do a local publish.

Below is a snippet from the output window. I would appreciate any suggestions for troubleshooting this issue. I have already tried to repair, uninstall, and reinstall VS.

```
2>Done building project "MyProject.Mvc".
2>Publishing folder /...
2>
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 5 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Best regards,
Vinney

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This the the same problem in this question and there is a workaround.
[Visual Studio 2012 Web Publish doesn't copy files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201146/visual-studio-2012-web-publish-doesnt-copy-files/12393154#12393154)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Roberto. I didn't find this previously.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer did not work for me; however, deleting and recreating the publish profile worked.

Comment: Deleting my profile worked for me as well. This was with VS 2010 premium.