# Visual Studio 2012 not publishing project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-7, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2012 web project that I am publishing to a Windows Server 2008 R2 server. I was having issues with the updates I was making locally not working on the remote server. When I checked the "Delete all existing files prior to publish" it successfully deleted the files from the server but then didn't add the new files - and yet claimed (in VS2012) that the publishing had been successful.

If I copy the PackageTmp folder up into the directory on the server manually, then everything works fine. Why is VS 2012 thinking it is copying but isn't really?

Comment: As you clean and rebuild the project prior to publish - is it working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Visual Studio 2012 Web Publish doesn't copy files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201146/visual-studio-2012-web-publish-doesnt-copy-files)

And [Microsoft connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/746321/publish-web-application-fails)