# Publish Website Getting Empty Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, publishing

I Have Build project with visual studio but when i want to publish my website i get an empty folder and nothing there ! no error or warning ,

```
Building directory '/project/Users/'.
Pre-compilation Complete
------ Publish started: Project: F:\...\project\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Connecting to site E:\project...
Publishing directory /...
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

e:\project is empty

Comment: Are you publishing locally or onto a remote server?

Comment: Take a look at this post, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201146/visual-studio-2012-web-publish-doesnt-copy-files

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Build your project (not rebuild) it will work :)

OR

Other workaround is publish in debug mode first then change settings and publish in release mode. it will surely work :)

Comment: You also have to make sure that your deployment path ends with a ` \ `. Otherwise the deployment folder will be empty.

Answer (score 10):

In my case there was a little item in the .csproj file that I had to remove. I had to unload the project, edit the .csproj, then hunt down and remove the following XML tag:

```
<Target Name="GatherAllFilesToPublish">     
</Target>
```

Once I republished, all was well.

Comment: For whatever reason I had (2) of these elements in my .csproj file - removed them both.

Answer (score 7):

Try building the project in release mode first then publish.

Comment: I changed the configuration from Release - Any CPU to Release - X86 and it worked.  Changed it back to Release - Any CPU and it now works as expected

Answer (score 4):

Creating a new profile helps solved my problem.

[How to: Deploy a Web Project Using One-Click Publish in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In `visual studio 2013` there is a bug that will produce empty folder when you publish only if you are using existing publish profile/settings. The existing profile setting may have come from code you checkout or got from another source. `The solution` is to create your own publish profile from scratch and make a new folder for it.

[image]

Start wizard from beginning.

[image]

Comment: Created a new publish profile and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the `Properties` **>** `Build Action` of your files if it was set to `None`. If it is, it will not copy your files, just the folders. On my project, it was set to

> Build Action = Content

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue with vs2015 update 3. I had changed my build folder (due to paths too long error), and i can see the last steps in the publish output:

> Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
>
> 3>D:\DEPLOYED_SITES\BUILD_TEMP\Package\PackageTmp

So i can at least get to the files in the PackageTmp folder.  I could create a post build event which can copy the build files to the correct output folder.

Comment: Did you found any solution?I have the same issue and nothing from the above resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had checked on "Include IIS settings as configured in IIS express" in the project properties << Package/Publish Web *" section. Once I unchecked this option the publish worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Recreate publish profile this should resolve

Answer (score 0):

for me, I

1. created a new publish profile
2. Rebuilt the site
3. Published the site

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because of a line in a root Directory.Build.props file:

```
<IsPublishable>false</IsPublishable>
```

This made all projects non-publishable by default (e.g., libraries and unit tests), and projects that needed to be published had to explicitly set `<IsPublishable>true</IsPublishable>` in their .csproj file (e.g., .EXEs).

Unfortunately, when publishing a Blazor web assembly project with IsPublishable=false, the publish step still does a whole bunch of work optimizing assemblies, etc., but it produces no output. There was no visual indication that the IsPublishable property was involved and overriding the important final step. After I tracked this property down and set it to true, then publishing the Blazor project did a lot more work and actually produced output.