# Visual Studio 2013 publish to file system not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, publish

I have tried many tricks but my Visual Studio won't publish my solution anywhere over the file system.  I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional.  The solution is MVC 5 with Razor.

I have tried deleting all my publish profiles, changing between debug and release and nothing seems to work.

I am not sure if it might be related by the Razor helpers and ViewBag are not recognized in the views. I have checked all of the versions and my System.Web.Mvc is 5.2.3.0 and all references in the webconfigs seem to match that.

This is probably two separate questions but wasn't sure if one might have something to do with the other.

When publishing it says it succeeded at the end but the folder is totally empty.

Comment: Try looking at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073284/publish-website-getting-empty-folder) and see if any of the answers work for you.

Comment: Please read [ask] and share your research (_"I have tried many tricks"_ does not suffice). What configuration are you building in, and what configuration does your publish profile use?

Comment: My second sentence states what I tried:

I have tried deleting all my publish profiles, changing between debug and release and nothing seems to work.

Comment: @bigphildogg86 Does your code runs in localhost? If so that's not a problem with Razor and ViewBag but probably more a configuration issue.

Comment: Look into your output tab and search for a line that says Web App was published successfully file///[PATH]. This is the path where your files have been published