# Visual studio 2017 Verbose publish

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, publish

I'm attempting to publish a .Net-Core 2.0 project on visual studio 2017.
When I publish everything builds fine the publish says success however no files are published.

I've looked at a few [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073284/publish-website-getting-empty-folder) about this and attempted the solution, switch from debug to release, etc.
But nothing seems to work

> Connecting to ftps://fakeServer.GoDaddy.com:21...
>   Restore completed in 97.58 ms for C:\source\MyProject.csproj.
>   Restore completed in 73.07 ms for C:\source\MyDependency.csproj.
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): Warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): Warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
>   MyProject-> C:\source\MyProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64\MyProject.dll
>   MyProject -> C:\source\MyProject\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64\PubTmp\Out\
>   Publishing folder /...
>   Web App was published successfully ftps://fakeServer.GoDaddy.com:21/

How can I enabled Verbose logging for .net-core projects?

Comment: Can you try publishing to a local folder en then try to upload the files to godaddy?

Comment: @MarioBerthely thanks that’s a good work around for the time being

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is for vs 2015 but for 2017 the settings are the same: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx

> To change the amount of information included in the build log On the
>   menu bar, choose Tools, Options.
>
> On the Projects and Solutions page, choose the Build and Run page.
>
> In the MSBuild project build output verbosity list, choose one of the
>   following values, and then choose the OK button.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll test this out, maybe it will atleast tell me why it won’t publish

Answer (score 0):

Are you showing no files at all?  I've  had visual studio lock the publish folder before.  Attempt to publish in administrator mode, and also try deleting all the existing files if any.  It's notable that i have mine set to delete automatically but i've still had to manually do it twice in the last three months.