# Visual Studio 2013 Preview: No Publish To File System?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

So I've built my project and I want to use the VS2008/2010/2012 "Publish To File System" option in Visual Studio 2013 Preview to push my project to a staging server for testing... but I can't find it anywhere in any of the menus.

It's bad enough that they've randomly rearranged the menu structures and items for TFS, but this change basically makes it impossible for me to recommend 2013 to anyone, much less the CTO, as an upgrade path.

Answer (score 20):

This can be accomplished easily:

1. Right click on project in Solution Explorer
2. Click **Publish**
3. Under **Profile** select `<New Custom Profile...>`
4. Create profile name (can be anything, dev.domainname.com)
5. Under **Connection** > **Publish Method** > select **File System**
6. Enter the **Target location** `\\server\sharedfolder\`

The rest of the settings are common as they were in the past.

The next time you go to publish just select the profile and you are done.

Comment: When you select the Publish Method, the drop-down may appear to be empty. In my case it was because this drop-down was not properly displaying in the VS2013 Dark Theme, and was rendering white-on-white text. Mousing over the invisible options revealed them!

Answer (score 5):

With two other people looking over my shoulder and making random suggestions, we finally stumlbed across the answer.  It turns out that VS2013 *requires* you to create a New Profile for each and every publish you make for each and every project in your solution.  Hmm. :-\

[image]

Comment: If you right-click on your project under Solution Explorer, there is no context menu option "Publish..."?

Comment: Finding "Publish" isn't the problem. Having a wizard (really?!?!) pop up that *requires* you to create a profile any time you want to publish to the file system is yet one more step backwards in the VS IDE.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, running Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 the publish web dialog looks a bit different, screenshot below:

[image]

1. Choose "Custom"
2. Give the profile a name and hit OK.
3. Select "File system" as the preferred publishing method...

Answer (score 2):

The first time in to VS 2013 you will not have a "New Profile" option as described by KeyOfJ.

This worked:

1. Right click on project in Solution Explorer
2. Click “Publish”. A “Publish Web” dialog box pops up.
3. Under tab “Profile”, in “Select a publish target”, select “Custom”. A “New Custom Profile” box pops up
4. Enter a “Profile name” and click “OK”
5. In tab “Connection” under “Publish Method”, choose “File System”
6. In tab “Connection” enter a “Target location”. Click “Next”
7. Under “Settings”, click on “File Publish Options”. Click “Next”
8. Click “Publish”

Next time you want to publish this project, VS. 2013 will default to the Profile name you just entered, and you will be able to publish in one click.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find Team Explorer? View -> Team Explorer.
Click Commits, and you can see "Publish to Remote Repository". Type in TFS URL or other Git repo to upload your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fake web connection and then reenter data, selecting Local File System.