# FTP is not an available option as publish target in VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ftp

I need to publish the site via FTP but when I right click and choose publish, FTP is not an option. What do I need to do to publish this via FTP?

[image: Can not publish via ftp?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in two steps.

1. Publish to the filesystem - see [Visual Studio 2013 Preview: No Publish To File System?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262274/visual-studio-2013-preview-no-publish-to-file-system)
2. Upload the files to ftp server using ftp client.