# Publishing projects without VS Publish

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Our team has been having quite a lot of trouble with Visual Studio's publish feature.  We use TFS and are all running VS 2012 ultimate.  It works fine when only one person is involved in a project, but when we get many people inside one project, the publish profiles get off and Visual Studio reports a successful publish even when all files haven't been copied up.  I've read all the SO questions about why this happens and I understand that TFS adds the publish profiles to the source control automatically.  If we create a new publish profile and republish, everything works.  But this is not sustainable.  I can't prevent VS from automatically adding the publish profiles to TFS (if we could, I think this would solve the problem) so I'm now looking for better ways to publish an application to a web server.  Is there a better tool out there to publish web applications or do I need to write my own VS extension?

Comment: I don't think this answers your question, but if you haven't read it yet then you should: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Per this question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12393154)

The temporary answer seems to be to change your settings from release to debug, save, then switch it back.  This causes the pubxml.user file to be rebuilt, which is actually the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I've read that and with too many projects to count, it isn't sustainable long term.  I don't want to have to tell every one of my developers to do one more step before publishing.  I want something reliable and scalable.

Comment: @Josh: I understand.  I haven't found the publish command to be reliable at all.  Even in small environments it will sometimes get sideways and not actually copy the files to the publish directory..  From what I can tell VS attempts to cache a lot of things that simply don't need to be cached.  We still use it, simply because I haven't found a decent alternative.