# The code behind file is not being updated when published to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am working on an `ASP.NET` project which is published to a configured IIS in the same machine.

I have made changes in one of the forms and than published it.

But while the changes on the web from file (`.aspx`) are being updated - other changes which reside in the code behind file (`.aspx.cs`) are not being updated.

My aim is to search addresses from a database and to display markers on google map.

Everything is working fine from my VS-IDE execution but after publishing it to the local IIS:
The front end is working fine while the back-end (the related `.aspx.cs`) does not work.

I tried those steps to remedy the situation:

1. I have deleted app directory from `windows/frameworks/4.0/temp files`.
2. I have even made new profile in publish wizard and published the project from a new folder.
3. I have deleted pool from IIS and made new one and mapped it to new ddl files folder.
4. I have also gone to project `/properties/publish web/items` to deploy and set to all files in the project.

But none of that solved the problem........

I am using

1. VS 2012
2. SQL Server 2012
3. EF 4.5

Comment: Did you try resetting iis or manually copying the changes?

Comment: See if anything posted in this thread helps.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201146/visual-studio-2012-web-publish-doesnt-copy-files

Answer (score 2):

Do a clean and rebuild, then publish. Sometimes, sometimes, a change to a dll won't be detected and so won't be recompiled.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete everything in the bin directory wherever you're publishing the site, then try to publish again.  Sometimes VS doesn't like to overwrite the dlls when publishing.

Answer (score 0):

This is very late but search brought me here. The solution that worked for me was, in Visual Studio:

1. In solution explorer, right click on your project -> select "Build Dependencies", remove any incorrect dependencies.
2. In solution explorer, go to Project -> References, remove any unnecessary references.
3. Make sure your project is selected in solution explorer, on PROJECT top menu, select "Convert to Web Application." Ok.
4. Clean and Rebuild your project.
5. Publish. It helps to set your File Publish option in Publish Profile to "Delete All Existing Files Prior to Publish"

The code behind files do not get uploaded, because they don't need to get uploaded. Only config and markup files. All the project code is contained in your project's DLL file in the BIN folder.

Hope this helps somebody out there.