# Visual Studio 2013 filesystem publish of website site fails

Tags: visual-studio-2013, publish

I am trying to publish an MVC website to the local file system. This works initially but after a few times it stops working. The publish profile is Release (Any CPU) but the output i get is:

```
------ Publish started: Project: MyWebsite.InternalAPI.2, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
12>Connecting to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\InternalApi...
12>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
12>obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp.
12>Publishing folder /...
12>Site was published successfully file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/InternalApi
12>
========== Build: 11 succeeded, 0 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have looked at the question posted here: [Visual Studio 2012 Web Publish doesn't copy files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201146/visual-studio-2012-web-publish-doesnt-copy-files)
and I have tried all the solutions in the answers without success.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: The output that you posted shows that the publish succeeded.  What is happening that indicates that it failed?  Are modified files not being copied?

Comment: No files at all are being copied. Also despite this being a release build there seems to be an attempt to copy files to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp