# visual studio 2015 web deploy fail with no error message

Tags: web, visual-studio-2015, deployment

Thanks for any help in advance.

A. I try to right-click/publish/web-deploy/preview/publish (everything is ok and message said "1 success").

B. But, no any file (cshtml, dll) is copy from my VS to IIS server.

C. If I manually copy the file to server, it worked.

details :

1. the first deploy is working from VS project (in different server) to Server. (I do try to use original VS project to deploy again but no luck.)
2. any new changing are not copied
3. visual studio 2015 update 3 & Windows Server 2012 r2 IIS 8

I search and people said in MS site that this is bug in VS 2012 and been fixed.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/746321/publish-web-application-fails

Is this bug happened in VS 2015 or I need to install and update ?
Thanks.

p.s. I try all followings but no luck:

- to set it to release-debug-release as work-around in VS 2012
- to check/un-checked "remove files on destination" option
- to right-click a *.cs file (because no way to select *.dll file) & select "publish this.cs" & it said 'success' in Web Publish Activity window. But not work.

(as above : to right-click a *.cshtml file & select "publish this.cs" & it said 'success' in Web Publish Activity window. It works.)

Thanks.

Comment: More detail :

I found similar question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201146/visual-studio-2012-web-publish-doesnt-copy-files/12393154#12393154

I reviewed that posting and had already try every single solution. But no luck to me.

It seems that people are talking about VS 2012 but my VS is 2015 update 3.